# How can use variable model several time in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can use variable model several time, something like this code:

```
$Db = Model::where(['user_id'=>1]);

$Db->first();

$Db->get();

$Db->delete();
```

I dont want using repeat `$Db` for get,first,delete or etc
for example I dont prefer using bad code something like this:

```
$Db = Model::where(['user_id'=>1])->first();
$Db = Model::where(['user_id'=>1])->get();
$Db = Model::where(['user_id'=>1])->delete();
```

or ...

I want separate class object for any `first()` or `get()` or ...

Comment: I didn't understand your question ,you want share your variable between several controllers and views?

Comment: @wahdan No, I don't want every time repeat model `$Db` for `first()` or `get()`, when one time you use `$Db->get();` after that if you want use `$Db->first();` that is not working coz first you do that for `first()`

Comment: What isn't working with your first example? So long as you do not overwrite `$Db`, you should be able to re-use the same query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$Db = Model::where(['user_id'=>1]);

with(clone($Db))->first();

with(clone($Db))->get();

with(clone($Db))->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but try using query builder https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#introduction

```
$qb = DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100);
$qb->get();
$qb->first();
$qb->delete();
```

Another option is to use a closure

```
$model = function() {
    return Model::where(['user_id'=>1]);
};

$model()->get();
$model()->first();
$model()->delete();
```

Again, not tested :)

Comment: you meant we cant using `model` for this method? coz I have relationship in that model. how can use that is I using query builder?

Comment: not that I know of - but I also never tried so I can't say for sure

Comment: ok. right. I have relationship in that model. how can use that if I using query builder?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to select models with a query builder :( you could do a join but if your app depends on models then this is probably not the right solution for you

Comment: @MikelWilliams see update, you might be able to use an anonymous function in order to avoid repeating code

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do is to create a helper or class.

// create

```
public static function user_info($user_id) {
    return Model::where(['user_id' => $user_id]);
}
```

// call

```
Helpers:user_info(1)->first();
Helpers:user_info(1)->get();
Helpers:user_info(1)->delete();
```